# To get background_gradient plot for all data frames in the for loop

Tags: python, visualization

I tried the below code to get the background_gradient plot for each diabetes_group. It is giving me only plot for the last group in the plot. How to get background_gradiant for all items (`x`) in `diabetes_group` with item name on the top ?

Subset of `df` before `groupby` looks like

```
Diabetes_Group  DM-1    DM-2    corr
Group1  56  56  1
Group1  56  58  0.611
Group1  56  61  0.448
Group1  56  63  0.3587
Group1  58  56  0.611
Group1  58  58  1
Group1  58  61  0.60113
Group1  58  63  0.534858
Group1  61  56  0.448
Group1  61  58  0.60113
Group1  61  61  1
Group1  61  63  0.622206
Group1  63  56  0.3587
Group1  63  58  0.534858
Group1  63  61  0.622206
Group1  63  63  1
Group2  78  78  1
Group2  78  85  0.622703
Group2  78  94  0.622244
Group2  78  23  0.687826
Group2  85  78  0.622703
Group2  85  85  1
Group2  85  94  0.697313
Group2  85  23  0.612089
Group2  94  78  0.622244
Group2  94  85  0.697313
Group2  94  94  1
Group2  94  23  0.603834
Group2  23  78  0.687826
Group2  23  85  0.612089
Group2  23  94  0.603834
Group2  23  23  1
Group3  27  27  1
Group3  27  80  0.118955
Group3  27  147 0.32038
Group3  27  9   0.335264
Group3  80  27  0.118955
Group3  80  80  1
Group3  80  147 0.430287
Group3  80  9   0.406426
Group3  147 27  0.32038
Group3  147 80  0.430287
Group3  147 147 1
Group3  147 9   0.546452
Group3  9   27  0.335264
Group3  9   80  0.406426
Group3  9   147 0.546452
Group3  9   9   1
```

`My code`

```
corr_matrix = []

for x, group in df.groupby('diabetes_group'):
    matrix = group[["diabetes_group", 'DM-1', 'DM-2', 'corr']]
    matrix_pivot = pd.pivot_table(matrix, values = 'corr', index=['DM-1'], columns=['DM-2'])
    d = matrix_pivot.style.background_gradient(cmap='Set3')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  M__

Answer (score 1):

```
corr_matrix = []

for x, group in df.groupby('diabetes_group'):
    matrix = group[["diabetes_group", 'DM-1', 'DM-2', 'corr']]
    matrix_pivot = pd.pivot_table(matrix, values = 'corr', index=['DM-1'], columns=['DM-2'])
    d = matrix_pivot.style.background_gradient(cmap='Set3').set_caption(x)
    display(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I am really late answering, the `set_caption` was cool.

**Background** What we are talking about here is the `style` Class in `pandas` of which `set_background` is one method. Usually, it is for outputting a `pandas` dataframe as a webpage. If I was front-end developer it would be cool. In this example it is used to colour the different bits of the dataframe, presumably to make it easier to read a lot of data.

The thing I would have done is dump to Excel. This will preserve the colouration. The bits contained within `#` are my codes.

```
from Pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

##########
path = Path('/path/todir/')
##########
for x, group in df.groupby('diabetes_group'):
    matrix = group[["diabetes_group", 'DM-1', 'DM-2', 'corr']]
    matrix_pivot = pd.pivot_table(matrix, values = 'corr', index=['DM-1'], columns=['DM-2'])
    d = matrix_pivot.style.background_gradient(cmap='Set3').set_caption(x)

    ##########
    pathout = Path(path, x + '.xlsx')
    d.to_excel(pathout)  
    ##########
```

What was happening originally was the 'loop' was overriding the diabetes `Group` in previous loop, hence appeared to be disappearing. What will happen now is an excel file will be produced separately for each group and the file name labeled as `Group1.xlsx`, `Group2.xlsx` etc ...

Here I dumped my test output to HTML simply via `to_html` and then to pdf.

[image]

**Notes**
The variable `corr_matrix = []` does not take part in this code. It may be important to other bits of code. I'm not sure `matrix` variable does much, but I've not checked.

The issue with IPython `display` is the output is not saved, so the code needs to be run each time the analyst wants to examine the correlation coefficients between `DM-1` and `DM-2`.

---

My personal dataframe was

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'diabetes_group':['Group1','Group1','Group2','Group2', 'Group3','Group3'],'DM-1':[56,56,56,56,56,56], 'DM-2':[56,58,61,63,56,58], 'corr':[0.2,0.3,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.1]})
```